# How to prove $f$ is an even function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functions

Suppose $g$ is any odd function, and we have $\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)g(t)dt=0$ and $\int_{-1}^{1} f(-t)g(t)dt=0$, $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[-1,1]$, how to show that $f$ is an even function, that is $f(t)=f(-t)$?

I considered the integral $\int_{-1}^{1} (f(t)-f(-t))g(t)dt=0$, and this is for all odd function $g(t)$. First I looked the case $f(t)-f(-t)$ is always $0$, then it is obvious. Then I discussed $f(t)-f(-t)$ is not always $0$, this implies $(f(t)-f(-t))g(t)$ must be an odd function, then it is easy to get $f(t)=f(-t)$ since $g$ is an odd function.

But I do not know whether this is correct, it seems I missed something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to point out that the two premises are actually redundant. If $\int_{-1}^1 f(t) g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = 0$ for all odd $g$, then $t \mapsto g(-t) = -g(t)$ is also an odd function, and so$$\int_{-1}^1 f(-t) g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{-1}^1 f(t)g(-t) \, \mathrm{d}t = 0.$$

Comment: You are correct. The second integral is actually derived from the first one, just change $-t$ by $u$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $g(t)=f(t)-f(-t)$ is odd, as $g(-t)=f(-t)-f(t)=-g(t)$. This gives $\int_{-1}^1|f(t)-f(-t)|^2dt=0$. But this is possible if and only if $|f(t)-f(-t)|^2$ is identically $0$, which means that $f(t)=f(-t)$ for all $t$, i.e. $f$ is even. Your reasoning is mostly correct, be confident about what you did! It is unnecessary to distinguish the cases if $f(t)-f(-t)$ is identically $0$ or not, you can get the result without splitting into cases (as I explained above).

P.S: If it is not clear to you why $\int|h(t)|=0\implies h\equiv0$ when $h$ is continuous, do it as an exercise. If you have questions, feel free to ask about it.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. This is a nice way!